# JSTL variables not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

I wrote the following code:

```
<%
        int accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("accountNumber"));
        int depositAmount = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("depositAmount"));
    %>
    <sql:query var='account' dataSource="jdbc/bank">
        select * from account where AccountNumber=<%= accountNumber %>      
    </sql:query>
    <c:forEach var="result" begin="0" items="${account.rows}">
        <c:set var="balance" value="${ result.balance + depositAmount }" />
        <c:out value="${ balance }" />
    </c:forEach>
```

The problem is that for `<c:set var="balance" />` it isn't actually adding the two values together.

I'm assuming that depositAmount isn't recognized? I'm not sure why.

Can someone please explain how I can use JSTL to get the request parameter (balance) and add it to the balance obtained in the query?

This is a homework assignment where I must use JSP.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

*Scriptlets* (those `<% %>` things) and EL (those `${}` things) doesn't share the same variable scope.

[**Get rid**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) of *scriptlets* and use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) only. Request parameters are in EL available by just `${param.name}`.

```
<sql:query var="account" dataSource="jdbc/bank">
    select * from account where AccountNumber=${param.accountNumber}      
</sql:query>
<c:forEach var="result" begin="0" items="${account.rows}">
    <c:set var="balance" value="${result.balance + param.depositAmount}" />
    <c:out value="${balance}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you for the information and the help. I've been banging my head off a desk for the last two hours.